# Safe cast to hash map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

How can I safely cast a Map to a hash Map?

I want to avoid class cast exception

```
HashMap<String, String> hMap;

public void setHashMap(Map map){
    hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) map;
}
```

Comment: Why would `setHashMap()` require a `Map` when it really needs a `HashMap`?

Comment: What do you mean by "safely"? What do you want to happen when it cannot be cast? Would making a copy be acceptable?

Comment: An external library i am using is implemented using an hashmap instead of a regular interface... :(

Comment: @Thilo I guess it would but if I can delegate to a library that would be ideal like the apache utils or something

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can make a (shallow) copy:

```
HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
```

Or cast it if it's not a HashMap already:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = 
   (map instanceof HashMap) 
      ? (HashMap) map 
      : new HashMap<String, String>(map);
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, you cannot typecast a `Map` to a `HashMap` without risk of a class-cast exception.  If the `Map` is a `TreeMap` then the cast will (and must) fail.

You can *avoid* the exception by making using `instanceof` to check the type before you cast, but if the test says "not a HashMap" you are stuck.  You won't be able to make the cast work.

The practical solutions are:

- declare `hMap` as a `Map` not a `HashMap`,
- copy the `Map` entries into a newly created `HashMap`, or
- (yuck) create a custom HashMap subclass that wraps the real map.

(None of these approaches will work in all cases ... but I can't make a specific recommendation without more details of what the map is used for.)

---

And while you are at it, it might be appropriate to lodge a bug report with the providers of the problematic library.  Forcing you to use a specific Map implementation is (on the face of it) a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should be as below to avoid any kind of exception such as `ClassCastException` or `NullPointerException`. Here any kind of `Map` object will be assigned to `HashMap` into your field of the class.

```
public void setHashMap(Map<String, String> map) {

    if (map != null && map instanceof HashMap<?, ?>) {
        hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) map;
    } else if (map != null) {
        hMap.putAll(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not cast to HashMap! Cast to Map!
If you really have a reason for your question, then, you have to create a new HashMap in case Map is not an instance of Map.
But this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (map instanceof HashMap) {
   hMap = (HashMap<String, String>) map;
} else {
  //do whatever you want instead of throwing an exception
}
```

or just surround the cast with a try/catch and capture the exception when it happens.

Comment: Assuming of course that `map` isn't a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, because if it is, then just checking `instanceof HashMap` won't work. Any calls like `String s = map.get("foo")` will throw the `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to always assume that it's a `HashMap<String, String>`, why not just do this?

```
HashMap<String, String> hMap;

public void setHashMap(HashMap<String, String> map){
    hMap = map;
}
```

If you want something more generic that will accept any `Map`:

```
public void setHashMap(Map<String, String> map){
    if (map != null)
        hMap = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
    else
        hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

No casting required. Also, your example was missing the return type. I've assumed that you meant to put `void`.